# Is "krapfens" commonly used to designate donuts?

Tags: language, pastry, german-cuisine

"Krapfen" is a German word which means "donuts".
I wonder if the term "krapfens" is commonly used in English to refer to donuts or if it may be pretty odd.
I have such doubt because it sounds similar to "crap" and it might sound not very good to designate food...

In other terms, if I say "Krapfens" in England / America does everyone understand what I meant to point out?

Comment: I'm curious, why did you think the German word might be used in English?

Comment: because it seems to me that in Italy it's used commonly -> http://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Krapfen.html . The italian word should be "bomboloni"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be stumbling about the fact that "[Krapfen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krapfen)" is more ambiguous that your Krapfen = donut conclusion.

1. The small piece of yeast-based dough, often filled and/or fried.
   That's the category your "Krapfen" and donuts fall into. In many dialects they are also called "**Kreppel**". (And a bunch of other names.)
2. Filled pasta dough, sweet or savoury, typically folded and/or crimped together.
   While an Italian would talk about "ravioli", an Estern European about "pieroggi" and an Asian about "dumplings", someone from Southern Tyrol or the Allgäu would call them "Krapfen" (but also use the term for the variety above) and in Jiddish cuisine it's a "[**kreplach**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreplach)".

So if you want a donut, say so. The term *krapfen* won't mean anything to an English speaker (check your favourite dictionary, I just did!). But don't be surprised if you are offered kreplach and get a ravioli, not a donut.

Answer (score 4):

I can only answer as to the USA. In the US, English speakers do not say krapfen, nor would most English speakers be familiar with the word.

Comment: I've never heard the term used (even in areas of high German descent in the US).